# Redis start as service [unrecognized service error]

Tags: caching, redis, ubuntu-14.04

I  install redis on Ubuntu 14.04.  I want to start redis as service. but I can't do that.
firstly , I cant start and stop redis server by using following commands:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/redis-server start
sudo /etc/init.d/redis-server stop
```

But I try  following command to start as service  , I get  "redis-service: unrecognized service"

```
sudo service redis-service start
```

I wait your helps, thanks

Answer (score 8):

try: `sudo service redis-server start`

Answer (score 7):

If you've used the defaults, your Redis service is actually named `redis_6379` - try the following:

```
sudo service redis_6379 start
```

Comment: unfortunetly dont work, we get same error

Answer (score 0):

I think,to configure `redis` as service,you need to execute below line.

```
sudo update-rc.d redis-server defaults
```

Comment: When tried this before .  but  don't work . When I try now , I get "System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/redis-server already exist"

Answer (score 0):

in your shell, use this command:  `redis-cli shutdown`
or
into folder src use: `./redis-server`